# How do I convert the styled-components css into a module in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
import styled from "styled-components";

// npm i @emailjs/browser

const Contact = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "replace with service id",
        "replace with template id",
        form.current,
        "replace with user id"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          console.log("message sent");
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };

  return (
    <StyledContactForm>
      <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" />
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    </StyledContactForm>
  );
};

export default Contact;

// Styles
const StyledContactForm = styled.div`
  width: 400px;
  form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    input {
      width: 100%;
      height: 35px;
      padding: 7px;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
      &:focus {
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 206, 158, 1);
      }
    }
    textarea {
      max-width: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 100px;
      min-height: 100px;
      padding: 7px;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
      &:focus {
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 206, 158, 1);
      }
    }
    label {
      margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      margin-top: 2rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: rgb(249, 105, 14);
      color: white;
      border: none;
    }
  }
`;
```

this code above in backticks

I want to convert the component style in these backticks using a module in React css
I wanna add a file named `import styles from "./Support.module.css";` and add it there but I can't get it right I use `className={styles.(thenameofthewhat I wanna style)}` I style it but I  fail to make it look exactly the same.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly convert the styled component styles to `css` but you can easily convert them to `scss`.

[This stackblitz (original styled-components)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-akfnx3?file=src%2FContact.js) displays your original form using styled-components.

And [this stackblitz (scss)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gf8mrf?file=src%2FContact.js,src%2FSupport.module.scss) displays the same form with the same ui using scss modules.

And [this stackblitz (css)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ymfqss?file=src%2FContact.js,src%2FSupport.module.css) displays the same form with the same ui using css modules.

You can convert the sass code to css with a free converter like [this site](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css).

You can create a file named `Support.module.css` with the converted css content:

```
.myCustomStyle {
  width: 400px;
}
.myCustomStyle form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.myCustomStyle form input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 7px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
.myCustomStyle form input:focus {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 206, 158, 1);
}
.myCustomStyle form textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
.myCustomStyle form textarea:focus {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 206, 158, 1);
}
.myCustomStyle form label {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.myCustomStyle form input[type='submit'] {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f9690e;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

And then in `Contact.js` will be like:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import styles from './Support.module.css';

const Contact = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(form.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.myCustomStyle}>
      <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" />
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Comment: Is there no possible way to convert it to css?

Comment: I don't know an easy way.

Comment: So isnt it possible that's what you mean? I think it can be done,

Comment: I'll look for it and update the answer in a while if I can find a way.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added another example accordingly.